# Excluding a Custom Post Type with a specific tag using pre_get_posts

Tags: custom-post-types, pre-get-posts, custom-post-type-archives

I have an archive page that lists a custom post type called 'event'. I have event posts with the tag 'regular', (the tag has an id of 53). I'd like to exclude these. I tried using pre_get_posts and then $query->set(('tag__not_in', array('53')) but I don't think tag__not_in will work with custom post types. Is there any way to fix this?

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_regular_tag');
function exclude_regular_tag( $query ){
    if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() )
        return;
    if ( is_home() ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( is_post_type_archive( 'event' ) ) {
        $args = array('53'); //id of 'regular' tag in custom post type 'event'
        $query->set('tag__not_in', $args);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: you're using the built in `post_tag` taxonomy? `tag__not_in` is post type agnostic, it just creates a [`tax_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) with the `NOT IN` operator. you can [see it in source here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.2/src/wp-includes/query.php#L1892). try having a look at the query in the template, `var_dump( $wp_query )` and see if it's applying your tax parameters.

Comment: ["tag__not_in"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      int(53)
    } This is in the query_vars array. I double checked the tag ID. It's definitely 53 but the post is still showing on the archive page. Any ideas?

Comment: ["tax_query"]=>
  object(WP_Tax_Query)#553 (2) {
    ["queries"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(5) {
        ["taxonomy"]=>
        string(8) "post_tag"
        ["terms"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          int(53)
        }
        ["include_children"]=>
        bool(true)
        ["field"]=>
        string(7) "term_id"
        ["operator"]=>
        string(6) "NOT IN"
      }
    }
    ["relation"]=>
    string(3) "AND"
  }

Answer (score 2):

I used tax_query instead of tag__not_in and it works now.

```
if ( is_post_type_archive( 'event' ) ) {

      $taxquery = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'event-tag',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => array( 53 ), //the ID of the event tag
            'operator'=> 'NOT IN'
        )
    );

    $query->set('tax_query', $taxquery);
    return;
}
```

Comment: It works because you are using a custom taxonomy, not the built in post tag taxonomy. `tag__not_in` only works for `post_tag`, not just any non-hierarchical taxonomy.